# Error while running metastore service on hive using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive, metastore

I have installed hive and initialized the derby schema successfully but when I start metastore service using command

```
hive --service metastore
```

I got the following error

```
Exception in thread "org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.JvmPauseMonitor$Monitor@2c62cd63" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.JvmPauseMonitor$Monitor
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.JvmPauseMonitor$Monitor.run(JvmPauseMonitor.java:176)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What Hive Version? What Java version did you install? Anything higher than Java 11 probably wont work

Comment: This error refers to libraries. It is anticipated that you are installing latest Hive version, check the Java version.

Comment: I am using java version 8 instead of 11 and hive version is 2.3.5